# Xamarin android get screen size in px

Tags: xamarin

Hi i am trying to get the screen size of device
I have tried this code:
    layout.Width;
    layout.Height;
but the width and the height are returning 0,0
anybody knows how to get the screen size?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin "DetectScreenSize" Recipe:

```
var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
var widthInDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.WidthPixels);
var heightInDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.HeightPixels);

private int ConvertPixelsToDp(float pixelValue)
{
    var dp = (int) ((pixelValue)/Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
    return dp;
}
```

re: https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/blob/master/Recipes/android/resources/device_specific/detect_screen_size/DetectScreenSize/Activity1.cs

Answer (score 0):

using [Xamarin.Essentials](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials)

```
  var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
  var realHeightInPx = mainDisplayInfo.Height;
```